# How do .plist files work in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, plist

I am new to iOS development, and I would like to know how `.plist` files work in iOS. Can any one help me by giving me an example of how to read an write data to and from a `.plist`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853735/how-can-we-create-our-own-plist-file-in-a-xcode-project

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yup:

```
NSString *rootPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *pListPath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Settings.bundle/Root.plist"];
NSDictionary *pList = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:pListPath];
```

Writing to a file isn't too hard either:

```
NSDictionary *dict;
NSData *data = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:dict format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 options:0 error:&error];
[data writeToFile:self.saveToPath atomically:YES];
```