# Failed to write data into plist file

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

I have check the method on the internet, but thats fail to update the data.

In the pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent method, I tested cameraCode, the key of the array has been changed after I choose different row in pickerView, but the value has not write in my plist file, which is named MultiSetting.plist, even though I write the statement:

```
path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MultiSetting" ofType:@"plist"];
[settingInfo writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Is there any can help me to improve my skill?

This is my code:

MultiSettingViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MultiSettingViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger *camNum;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIPickerView *picker;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *regionLabel;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *placeLabel;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *placeArray;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *settingArray;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIToolbar *doneToolbar;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSBundle *bundle;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *path;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSBundle *bundle1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *path1;


- (IBAction)segmentedControlIndexChanged;
- (void)doneBtn_OnClick:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)textfield_OnClick:(id)sender;

@end
```

MultiSettingViewController.m

```
#import "MultiSettingViewController.h"

@implementation MultiSettingViewController

@synthesize camNum, picker, placeArray, settingArray, textField, doneToolbar, segmentedControl, bundle, path, bundle1, path1, regionLabel, placeLabel;

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //NSLog(@"%i", camNum);

    bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    path = [bundle pathForResource:@"HK" ofType:@"plist"];  placeArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

    bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    path = [bundle pathForResource:@"MultiSetting" ofType:@"plist"];    settingArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

    if (self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0){
        NSInteger selectedRow = [self.picker selectedRowInComponent:0];

        NSDictionary *placeInfo = [placeArray objectAtIndex:selectedRow];
        [regionLabel setText:[placeInfo objectForKey:@"name"]];
    }

    if(self.doneToolbar == nil){
        self.doneToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];
        UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                                                                 target:self
                                                                                 action:@selector(doneBtn_OnClick:)];
        [self.doneToolbar setItems: [NSArray arrayWithObject:doneBtn]];
    }

    self.textField.inputView = self.picker;
    self.textField.inputAccessoryView = self.doneToolbar;
    self.textField.delegate = self;
    self.picker.delegate = self;
    self.picker.dataSource = self;
    self.picker.hidden = YES;


    self.doneToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    self.doneToolbar.hidden = YES; }

-(IBAction) segmentedControlIndexChanged{
    switch (self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex){
        case 0:
            bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
            path = [bundle pathForResource:@"HK" ofType:@"plist"];
            placeArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
            [self.picker reloadAllComponents];

            NSInteger selectedRow = [self.picker selectedRowInComponent:0];
            NSDictionary *placeInfo = [placeArray objectAtIndex:selectedRow];
            [regionLabel setText:[placeInfo objectForKey:@"name"]];
            break;
        case 1:
            bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
            path = [bundle pathForResource:@"KW" ofType:@"plist"];
            placeArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
            [self.picker reloadAllComponents];

            selectedRow = [self.picker selectedRowInComponent:0];
            placeInfo = [placeArray objectAtIndex:selectedRow];
            [regionLabel setText:[placeInfo objectForKey:@"name"]];
            break;
        case 2:
            bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
            path = [bundle pathForResource:@"TW" ofType:@"plist"];
            placeArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
            [self.picker reloadAllComponents];

            selectedRow = [self.picker selectedRowInComponent:0];
            placeInfo = [placeArray objectAtIndex:selectedRow];
            [regionLabel setText:[placeInfo objectForKey:@"name"]];
            break;
        case 3:
            bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
            path = [bundle pathForResource:@"TM" ofType:@"plist"];
            placeArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
            [self.picker reloadAllComponents];

            selectedRow = [self.picker selectedRowInComponent:0];
            placeInfo = [placeArray objectAtIndex:selectedRow];
            [regionLabel setText:[placeInfo objectForKey:@"name"]];
            break;
        case 4:
            bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
            path = [bundle pathForResource:@"TP" ofType:@"plist"];
            placeArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
            [self.picker reloadAllComponents];

            selectedRow = [self.picker selectedRowInComponent:0];
            placeInfo = [placeArray objectAtIndex:selectedRow];
            [regionLabel setText:[placeInfo objectForKey:@"name"]];
            break;
        case 5:
            bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
            path = [bundle pathForResource:@"ST" ofType:@"plist"];
            placeArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
            [self.picker reloadAllComponents];

            selectedRow = [self.picker selectedRowInComponent:0];
            placeInfo = [placeArray objectAtIndex:selectedRow];
            [regionLabel setText:[placeInfo objectForKey:@"name"]];
            break;
        case 6:
            bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
            path = [bundle pathForResource:@"LT" ofType:@"plist"];
            placeArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
            [self.picker reloadAllComponents];

            selectedRow = [self.picker selectedRowInComponent:0];
            placeInfo = [placeArray objectAtIndex:selectedRow];
            [regionLabel setText:[placeInfo objectForKey:@"name"]];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    } }

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIPickerViewDataSource methods
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {    return 1; }

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {   return [placeArray count]; }

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIPickerViewDelegate methods
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
             titleForRow:(NSInteger)row             forComponent:(NSInteger)component {     NSDictionary *placeInfo = [placeArray objectAtIndex:row];   return [placeInfo objectForKey:@"name"]; }

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView     didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
       inComponent:(NSInteger)component {   NSDictionary *placeInfo = [placeArray objectAtIndex:row];   NSString *name = [placeInfo objectForKey:@"name"];
    self.placeLabel.text = name;
    NSString *code = [placeInfo objectForKey:@"cameraCode"];

    NSMutableDictionary *settingInfo = [settingArray objectAtIndex:(NSInteger)camNum];
    NSLog(@"%@", [settingInfo objectForKey:@"cameraCode"]);
    [settingInfo setObject:code forKey:@"cameraCode"];
    NSLog(@"%@", [settingInfo objectForKey:@"cameraCode"]);
    path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MultiSetting" ofType:@"plist"];
    [settingInfo writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

    //[self obtainPic:cameraCode];

    /*aTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0
     target:self
     selector:@selector(timerFired:)
     userInfo:nil
     repeats:YES];
     */ }

- (void)doneBtn_OnClick:(id)sender{
    [self.textField endEditing:YES];
    self.picker.hidden = YES;
    self.doneToolbar.hidden = YES; }

- (IBAction)textfield_OnClick:(id)sender{
    self.picker.hidden = NO;
    self.doneToolbar.hidden = NO; }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated. }

@end
```

Really thanks for your sincerely help!

Comment: Actually not duplication, because obtain only the absolute directory cannot solve my problem, but still thanks for your sharing.

Comment: Yes, it is the same. You are trying to write to the app's resource bundle. You can't do that. You need to write your file elsewhere such as the `Documents` directory.

Comment: But the most important point is getting the path only is not enough to solve my problem......

Comment: You already know how to the write the file (call `writeToFile:atomically:`). The important part actually is using the proper path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything included in the main bundle is **read-only**; thus, you might have a Cocoa Error 513 (*"The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not permitted"*) in your log.

You have three others folders for data storage which are read/write : `Temp`, `Cache` and `Documents`

You might create your file `MultiSetting.plist` in the **Document folder** at runtime, then write into it.

---

You can retrieve the path to the document directory like this :

```
 NSArray * documentPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString * documentDirectory = [documentPath objectAtIndex:0];
```

---

### Edit

Then, you can copy your pList in there (*note that as stated before, it is read-only, so you won't be able to move it nor delete it from your bundle*). For this, use NSFileManagers's function [-copyItemAtPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html) :

```
- (BOOL)copyItemAtPath:(NSString *)srcPath toPath:(NSString *)dstPath error:(NSError **)error
```

Comment: Do you mean that I want to write the MultiSetting.plist into the document folder as a NSMutableArray? If yes, how to do that? Because the previous code you wrote is just create a path and directory. Thanks.

Comment: @user2541401 The code I gave is to retrieve (no creation here) the path to the Document Directory specific to your app: use it to create your pList there. There are plenty of posts on how to programmatically create files (for instance, [here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853735/how-can-we-create-our-own-plist-file-in-a-xcode-project)).

Comment: But actually, I already have a plist file. My problem is how to import the data in plist file into the document folder. Isn't it?

Comment: @user2541401 I edited my answer. Don't forget to include the filename in `dstPath` (it is specified in the docs), or it'll fail, trying to replace all the Document folder.

Comment: But even I use the above method, the situation become worse that the cameraCode have not been wrote in the NSMutableDictionary. 
The code: http://i.imgur.com/QBKFnA3.png

Comment: @Bigood: I guess you meant `NSFileManager`'s method `copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:`

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to write into a file that resides inside the application bundle. This is most certainly not the location for writing user settings to. And iOS won't let you either, as the sandbox blocks application write access to the app bundle.

Use the proper API to get a filesystem location where you can actually write. [Documentation is here.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH3-SW11)