# Creating Plist iOS

Tags: ios, plist

I'm trying to make a restaurant queue app whose first page will be with three buttons, one of them being 'New Reservation'. When clicked on it, it opens a new view that takes in the customers name,phone number and total number of people, the waiter will enter the estimated time for their order and press enter which will save all these values in a plist. I'm referring to youtube videos to create plist, but I have a view controller class in which I initialize the plist and also a NewReservation class that controls the saving data. According to the video I create the plist in viewDidLoad method and also copy few lines of it in the IBAction of the button "enter details". I'm jumbled up and can't access the values in my NewReservation class, please clarify.
Thank you.

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class NewReservation;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic , strong) NewReservation *Res;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
 #import "ViewController.h"
#import "NewReservation.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController{
    NSMutableArray *phoneNumbers , *name , *noOfPeople , *estTime;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.Res = [[NewReservation alloc] init];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Property List.plist"];

    if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]){
        plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Property List" ofType:@"plist"];
    }
    NSData *plistXML = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:plistPath];
    NSString *errorDesc = nil;

    NSPropertyListFormat format;

    NSDictionary *temp = (NSDictionary *) [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:plistXML options:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves format:&format error:&errorDesc];
    if(!temp){
        NSLog(@"Error Reading plist: %@ , format: %lu",errorDesc , format);
    }
    name = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[temp objectForKey:@"name"]];
    phoneNumbers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[temp objectForKey:@"phoneNumbers"]];
    noOfPeople = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[temp objectForKey:@"noOfPeople"]];
    estTime    = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[temp objectForKey:@"estTime"]];
    //Confused how to go further




}




- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

NewReservation.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NewReservation : UIViewController{

}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *name;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *phoneNumber;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *noOfPeople;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *estTime;
- (IBAction)nameReturn:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)enterDetails:(id)sender;



@end
```

NewReservation.m

```
#import "NewReservation.h"

@implementation NewReservation




- (IBAction)enterDetails:(id)sender{
    if([self.name.text isEqualToString:@""] || [self.phoneNumber.text isEqualToString:@""] || [self.noOfPeople.text isEqualToString:@""] || [self.estTime.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        UIAlertView *error = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops" message:@"You must complete all fields!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [error show];
    }
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Property List.plist"];

   //Cant continue here cause its confusing me, i need to add the values and update the list everytime a new 'name,noOfPersons,phoneNumber,estTime
    //is entered.


}


@end
```

Comment: Follow the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853735/how-can-we-create-our-own-plist-file-in-a-xcode-project

Answer (score 0):

An instance variable is unique to a class. By default, only the class and subclasses can access it. Therefore, as a fundamental principal of object-oriented programming, instance variables (ivars) are private—they are encapsulated by the class.

By contrast, a property is a public value that may or may not correspond to an instance variable. If you want to make an ivar public, you'd probably make a corresponding property. But at the same time, instance variables that you wish to keep private do not have corresponding properties, and so they cannot be accessed from outside of the class. You can also have a calculated property that does not correspond to an ivar…

Without a property, ivars can be kept hidden. In fact, unless an ivar is declared in a public header it is difficult to even determine that such an ivar exists.

Your child class have a properties that does not correspond to an ivar
To access the ivar with properties the ivar need to be synthesise properties in from child class.

```
 @implementation NewReservation
 @synthesize phoneNumbers, name, noOfPeople, estTime;
 // ****
 @end
```

Comment: Thanks, I realized. I recreated the app and figured it out. Though do you know how i can access my data from a plist maybe into an array and display them on my screen?